# iptables, what to open on INPUT for wget

Tags: linux, iptables, ddos

I am configuring my `iptables`. The policy for `OUTPUT` is `ACCEPT`. Though `INPUT` is `DROP`. I am wondering what I need to open up on `INPUT` so I can receive responses on outgoing traffic (automatic or manual, i.e. `wget`), without leaving me vulnerable to ddos attacks.

I'm thinking somehwere along the lines of

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Why not just make it simple and say `iptables -A INPUT --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`?

Comment: @Zoredache `-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` Don't forget `-m state --state` and you probably want related, too. (For FTP or other services that use dynamic port assignment.)

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to type `-m state`. Though, I'd rather go with MadHatter's approach since I'm trying to close the firewall as much as possible (since I'm handling data of a client on it).

Comment: That was @Zoredache, not you. :)

Comment: Well, me too (in my question). On another note, I'm not 100% familiar with the way ddos attacks work, are these all packets with a NEW state or will such an attack make use of an ESTABLISHED connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use `--sport 80`, not `--dport 80`; the traffic is coming **from** a web server.  But other than that, it should work, for `http://` requests.

Comment: You're right, always forgetting about `source/destination`. Will give it a quick try before accepting :)